# Changing "submitted on date" of comments

Tags: comments, date-time

How do I change the "submitted on date" of a comment to an earlier date? I want to change the date that is displayed to the readers. As far as I know, I can change the date of the post by clicking the "quick edit" option. Is there something similar I can do with comments?

Comment: But where do you want to do this, backend, frontend? Do you want to change only the date that is displayed in the site or do you want to change the date that's stored in the database? Please, expand your Question, you are free to [edit] it whenever needed.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you mean the format of the date that is displayed for the comment.

Different themes will do this different ways, but in general there should be a `comments.php` file which should contain what makes up a comment.

In here should be `wp_list_comments();`

You will need to add a callback in here which will allow you to override the comment functionality and create your own from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit the date of a comment, you probably should do that in the database.

[image: Comment database view]